# Unhandled exception 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified in dynamic recompiler

Tags: c, visual-studio, assembly, arm, win-universal-app

The code is a MIPS->ARM dynamic recompiler. After many times of running recompile_function(), it crashes at the condition clause of below code, though it can run this line of code without any issue during the earlier function running.

```
void recompile_function(){

    //recompilation code
    ......

    if (out > (u_char *)((u_char *)base_addr + (1 << TARGET_SIZE_2) - MAX_OUTPUT_BLOCK_SIZE - JUMP_TABLE_SIZE))
        out = (u_char *)base_addr;

    // other code
    ......
}
```

Variable out is the pointer used to write the recompiled code. base_addr always points to the original start of the allocated memory space. Variable out progresses 4 bytes each time an instruction is written, while base_addr keeps unchanged.

```
extern char extra_memory[33554432];
#define BASE_ADDR ((int)(&extra_memory))
void *base_addr;
u_char *out;

void new_dynarec_init()
{
    protect_readwrite();
    base_addr = ((int)(&extra_memory));
    out = (u_char *)base_addr;
}
```

The error is "Unhandled exception at 0x7738EC9F (ntdll.dll) in frontend.exe: 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified."

This is the disassemble code around the faulting clause instruction.

```
#if NEW_DYNAREC == NEW_DYNAREC_ARM
    __clear_cache((void *)beginning, out);
53830242  ldr         r1,[r9]  
53830246  add         r3,r4,r5,lsl #2  
5383024A  mov         r0,r7  
5383024C  str         r3,[r2]  
5383024E  blx         __clear_cache_bugfix (537D19DCh)  
    //cacheflush((void *)beginning,out,0);
#endif

// If we're within 256K of the end of the buffer,
// start over from the beginning. (Is 256K enough?)
    if (out > (u_char *)((u_char *)base_addr + (1 << TARGET_SIZE_2) - MAX_OUTPUT_BLOCK_SIZE - JUMP_TABLE_SIZE))
53830252  mov         r2,#0xAA98  
53830256  movt        r2,#0x5462  
5383025A  ldr         r3,new_recompile_block+0A1E8h (53830550h)  
5383025C  ldr         r4,[r2]  
5383025E  ldr         r2,[r9]  
53830262  add         r3,r3,r4  
53830264  cmp         r2,r3  
53830266  bls         new_recompile_block+9F06h (5383026Eh)  
        out = (u_char *)base_addr;
53830268  mov         r2,r4  
5383026A  str         r4,[r9]
```

It's the line the debugger prompts me. I checked the disassemble window that also points to this line. What's more, if I choose continue, a new error will pop up and the program will crash at the code line "__fastfail" in function __report_gsfailure. The new error is "Unhandled exception at 0x53831547 (mupen64plus.dll) in frontend.exe: Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun". 0x53831546 is the address of code line "__fastfail".

```
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4100) // unreferenced formal parameter
__declspec(noreturn) void __cdecl __report_gsfailure(GSFAILURE_PARAMETER)
{
5383153C  push        {r0,r1}  
5383153E  push        {r11,lr}  
53831542  mov         r11,sp  
    __fastfail(FAST_FAIL_STACK_COOKIE_CHECK_FAILURE);
53831544  movs        r0,#2  
53831546  __fastfail  
}

// Declare stub for rangecheckfailure, since these occur often enough that the
// code bloat of setting up the parameters hurts performance
__declspec(noreturn) void __cdecl __report_rangecheckfailure()
{
53831548  push        {r11,lr}  
5383154C  mov         r11,sp  
    __report_securityfailure(FAST_FAIL_RANGE_CHECK_FAILURE);
5383154E  movs        r0,#8  
53831550  bl          __report_securityfailure (53831558h)  
53831554  __debugbreak
```

The register PC   = 53831546 so the execution point is __fastfail.

Comment: That's unlikely to cause an invalid handle exception (it doesn't deal with handles at all). Either you determined the location of the crash wrong, or maybe it's an error from your debugger. Examine call stack to see how the execution ended up in ntdll.

Comment: @Jester It's the line the debugger prompts me. I checked the disassemble window that also points to this line. What's more, if I choose continue, a new error will pop up and the program will crash at the code line "__fastfail" in function __report_gsfailure. The new error is "Unhandled exception at 0x53831547 (mupen64plus.dll) in frontend.exe: Stack cookie instrumentation code detected a stack-based buffer overrun". 0x53831546 is the address of code line "__fastfail".

Comment: You should update the question with the disassembly around the faulting instruction. Also show how `base_addr` and `out` are defined.

Comment: What's the address for the first fault? The error message you posted `Unhandled exception at 0x7738EC9F` references an address not in your code, and you haven't otherwise indicated which instruction caused the problem first. Also examine call stack. If possible put breakpoint at start of your function and single step it on the instruction level to see where exactly the first problem occurs.

Comment: @Jester Just updated. Please check again.

Comment: Hey I was very interested in this project, did you succeeded with the port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by __clear_cache which is located above the crashed condition clause. Disabling that function call fixed the crash.